# monodroid supportmapfragment.map always return null

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, google-maps-android-api-2, supportmapfragment

I'm trying to use google maps version 2 by this code:

```
    public   void setMapData()
    {
        try {
            if (mapView == null && _mapFragment != null)
            {
                mapView = _mapFragment.Map;
                if (mapView != null)
                {
                    CameraPosition currentPlace = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                        .Target (currentProperty.Location)
                            .Bearing (0) 
                            .Zoom (((RPLApp)pshowAct.Application).typeOfShow .PropertyZoomLevel) //apply zoom here
                            .Build ();

                    mapView.AnimateCamera  (CameraUpdateFactory.NewCameraPosition (currentPlace));

                    mapView .Clear ();
                    MarkersHelperClass.DrawMarkerOnLocation (pshowAct , mapView, currentProperty.Location);
                }

            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            RltLog .HandleException (ex);
        }
    }
```

but `mapView = _mapFragment.Map;`  always return `null`. at below url has a solution for java codes but it is not working for monodroid. How can we use it at monodroid or c#? It is not suitable because the code defined a new class inside and activity. How we can make it friend with C# syntax?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14072348/1939409

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What component have you using for Google Maps? Have you tried Google Play Services? [How to implement google play services using android sdk 17 on xamarin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19559849/how-to-implement-google-play-services-using-android-sdk-17-on-xamarin/19562799#19562799)

EDIT:
Here is my layout (Resource.Layout.GoogleMap):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mapLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/mapView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
            //other controls
</RelativeLayout>
```

And my code:

```
public class GoogleMapActivity : Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentActivity
{
    private Android.Gms.Maps.GoogleMap _mapView;
    private Android.Gms.Maps.SupportMapFragment _fragment;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.GoogleMap);

        var mapOptions = new Android.Gms.Maps.GoogleMapOptions()
            .InvokeMapType(Android.Gms.Maps.GoogleMap.MapTypeNormal)
            .InvokeZoomControlsEnabled(false)
            .InvokeCompassEnabled(true);

        var fragTx = SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
        var mapFragment = Android.Gms.Maps.SupportMapFragment.NewInstance(mapOptions);
        fragTx.Add(Resource.Id.mapView, mapFragment, "mapView");
        fragTx.Commit();
    }

    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();

        _fragment = ((Android.Gms.Maps.SupportMapFragment)SupportFragmentManager.FindFragmentById(Resource.Id.mapView));
        _mapView = _fragment.Map;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please see my edit, I can not use the posted links solution because c# not support its syntax